# Using replace() with for loop for nested lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working with a set of data that is a list of lists.  I am trying to replace a part of an element in the nested lists; namely, there are quotes around some of the elements in these lists that I want to remove.

Here's my code so far:

```
for items in list:
   for i in range(len(items)):
        items[i] = items.replace("", '')
```

Of course, this produces an error because items is a list and not a string.  I've tried adding an [i] before the .replace to see if that makes a difference, but it doesn't make the changes that I want.   I'm new to Python and coding, so I'd love any insights--I find most of the other example that "kind of" fit my problem are more advanced than my understanding.

If it helps, I am using Python 2.7. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you give an example of the structure of your list of lists i.e `x = [[1,2,3],["hlleo", "something" , 0]]`

Comment: **Please** don't use list as a name for your own sequences, since it's the name of a builtin function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `items[i] = items[i].replace('"', '')`, but this might even be a little cleaner:

```
for sublist in lst:
    sublist[:] = [s.replace('"', '') for s in sublist]
```

Comment: wouldn't you need to do `replace('"', '')`?

Comment: Perhaps `strip` would be clearer than `replace`, but it's hard to tell from the question.

Comment: Thanks!  This was the issue.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida -- Yeah, or even `translate`, but that's a little more obscure:  `s.translate(None, '"')` would do the job of the current call to `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l
[['one', 'with"quote'], ['two', 'three', 'another"quote']]

>>> for items in l:
...   for i in range(len(items)):
...      items[i] = items[i].replace('"','')
... 
>>> l
[['one', 'withquote'], ['two', 'three', 'anotherquote']]
```